# Min of a real-valued Fourier transform

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $P$ be a compact, convex, symmetric, $d$-dimensional body in $\mathbb R^d$, and let $\mu$ be a (necessarily) symmetric probability measure on $P$, so that 
$\mu_P(x) = \mu_P(-x)$, for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$.  As a consequence, the Fourier transform 
$\hat \mu_P(\xi) := \int_{\mathbb R^d} exp(2\pi i \langle \xi \cdot x \rangle d \mu$) is real-valued.

Are there methods to find a $\bf{global}$ minimum (it's ok if it's not necessarily unique) of the (real-valued) Fourier transform 
$\hat \mu_P(\xi)$?

Note. Of course, one can find conditions for local minima and then employ a brute-force comparison of all of them, but there are potentially infinitely many local minima.  So I'm looking for something better than this. In other words, does the convexity of $P$ help us somehow?

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question?

Comment: Note that $\mu$ can be supported on a NONCONVEX subset of $P$ of arbitrarily horrible topology, so the convexity of $P$ does not seem to help -- you need more hypotheses to get something sensible.

Comment: Thanks, Igor, for your comment and for understanding the question.   I have a feeling that the answer is still quite meaningful, but perhaps we lack good tools to get there.  For example, if $P:= [-1/2, 1/2]$, its Fourier transform is the usual Sinc function, which has a global min at around $\xi = 1.4$, with the definition of the transform given above. It also has infinitely many other local minima, but they are larger.  Perhaps we should simply concentrate on the uniform measure?

Comment: I suspect that even with the uniform measure it might be
impossible to say anyting useful in general.  Suppose $d=2$
and let $P_0$ be the unit circle.  Then $\hat\mu_{P_0}(\xi)$
is a radial function involving a Bessel function, which has
a circle of global minima (if I did this right,
$\hat\mu_{P_0}(\xi) = J_1(2\pi\left|\xi\right|) / (2\pi\left|\xi\right|)$,
and the global minum is around $\left|\xi\right| \approx 0.817$).
Now if we perturb $P_0$ a bit to some symmetric and convex $P$,
there'll usually be a single pair $\pm\xi$ of global minima of $\hat\mu_P$
*somewhere* near that circle, ...

Comment: [interrupted by 600-character limit] ... but its position could jump
unpredictably depending on the perturbation.

Comment: @Noam:  Thanks Noam, yes, I completely agree with your analysis of the Bessel function, which of course generalizes to $d$-dim'l spherical shells.  I'm hoping that we could perhaps detect the part of the geometry of the perturbed object which tells us something about this new perturbed direction of the new global min $\xi$. For example, perhaps it's a function of the Gaussian curvature (and the corresponding points) for just a few selected points on the perturbed object.

Comment: I doubt it can even be that simple.  Suppose our perturbation is
to slightly flatten the disc $P_0$ in the same way at $2n$ points.
If they are equally spaced then we probably have $2n$ minima
forming a regular polygon.  But now rotate the $2n$ points freely
about the boundary of $P_0$, and who knows what happens to the
location of the minimum?

Comment: @Noam: I think I see what you're getting at, so it suggests restricting the class of object even further, to say 0-symmetric polygons P, so that the symmetry group of P becomes larger, though not quite as large as the orthogonal group which corresponded to the circle.

Comment: Also, any nice algorithm would be very welcome.  Let's note that for the unit interval, a brute-force derivative test tells us that it suffices to solve $x = tan(x)$ to find a global min for $sin x /x$.  Perhaps this suggests that maybe there is a fixed-point algorithm of some sort in general?

Comment: I suspect that the 1-dimensional case is misleading, since
(at least if you insist on uniform measure) there's only
one $\mu$ to try, so there's no scope for contriving
difficult instance.  In 2 dimensions, even polygons may be
too complicated: now I'll start from a regular $2n$-gon $P_0$,
whose Fourier transform should have a regular $2n$-gon of minima,
and then obtain $P$ by small polygonal truncations of the
corners of $P_0$.

Comment: NB even for a real-function $f$ of one variable it may be
basically impoossible to *locate* its minima with certainty,
even if the minimal *value* of $f(x)$ is known to high accuracy,
because (as in the planar examples I'm giving) there may be
several local minima $x_j$ for which one can't predict
how close $f(x_j)$ might be to $f(x_k)$ and thus how accurately
one might have to compute to decide the winner.

Comment: @Noam: thanks for your very interesting thoughts and efforts. I'm still hoping that something can be said, perhaps changing the measure to somehow correspond to the object, but I admit it might be a long-shot.